Cannot access folder no matter what I do
Our pipeline has failed recently because of a folder which it cannot delete as part of a pre-run cleanup. This folder contained testresults and is on a WS2019 VM which runs a GitLab runner which then executes the pipeline.
Apparently, the folder in question has been completely corrupted. I cannot access it in explorer.exe, I cannot access it through an elevated PS window, I cannot even access it through WSL running on the same machine. The first two options always ended with a permission denied error and the third option ended with the shell telling me that the folder in question does not exist.
Is there some doomsday tool which I can use to delete this folder? I do not care about its contents, that will be regenerated anyway. Another problem is that I do not have access to the hypervisor backend so I can't just attach the VHDX or whatever to a Linux VM and remove the folder that way. I would have to do it on the VM OS itself.
